# Removing the characters '*' and '\' from dataframe elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to remove the following characters from my dataframe- {space, ", ', \n, * and }. I am able to do it for the first four characters, but getting error for * and . Please help. The code I am using is-

```
df = df.replace(to_replace = ["'",'"'," ","\n","*","\"], value = ["","","","",""], regex=True)
```

also tried "\" inplace of "", still getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try espape values by `\` for special regex characters like `*`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['ss""ss',"dd'e",'ww\n','rrr*\\']})
df = df.replace(["'",'"'," ",r"\n",r"\*",r"\\"], '', regex=True)
print (df)
      a
0  ssss
1   dde
2    ww
3   rrr
```